# Max drive size for PERC H700 in Dell r610

Tags: storage, dell-poweredge, h700

I'm having a hard time understanding the spec. sheet. It says there is a max storage cap of 12TB for the entire system, but does not specify a disk size restriction.

Should I assume the HDD cap is 2TB (* 6 bays)? Any chance this 12TB is a soft cap (i.e. limit has raised with firmware updates)? I really want to max out the storage capacity of this unit.

Edit:
Spec link: http://www.dell.com/ai/business/p/poweredge-r610/pd

Comment: Maybe provide a link to the spec sheet?

Comment: @joeqwerty good call. Added

Comment: Hi @patrickgamer did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Got sucked into a memory problem. Voted accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Just to share my config, i got a PERC H700 (inside a R410 server) with the firmware version 12.3.0-0032 and my 4 new hard drives IronWolf 10 TB are seen as 2 TB drives. After upgrading the firmware to version 12.10.7-0001, they are now fully functionnal and i have create a big RAID 5 array.

According to [DELL forums](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/t/19639981), people reported to have 10TB drives working with Firmware Version `12.10.7-0001`.

Anyway there is [no such specification](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pvaul/en/perc-technical-guidebook.pdf) because according to DELL, they only support DELL drives. It's the same for newer [730](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell-PowerEdge-RAID-Controller-H730.pdf) and 740 models too. Datasheets don't talk about drives.

When you try to install drives newer than the controller, always look for controller's firmware updates before. At least, that's what I use to do.

I am answering here because I already had some positive experience with PERC H730 with 3TB drives and latest (at that time) firmware, don't remember the fw version though, in both DELL's R230 and T130, BTW *I googled all this in three minutes*.